# Allower user to add data to a SharePoint list through Power Apps , but not access the sharepoint UI?

Tags: permissions, powerapp

I'm pretty sure we've done it before by creating a special permissions called Add Only, but is there any way to keep those Power Apps users from being able to navigate native SharePoint? In particular the root and list default home pages?

Comment: The only option is to not give the users access to the site. You could create two sites: Site A where users have access to add data through the powerapp and site B where the data is finally stored and the users don't have access to. Then create a Flow that copies the data from site A to Site B when it is submitted and then delete the data from Site A. This approach can burn your flow runs if the app is frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to not give those users any access to that site.  Manually [create a connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-data-connection) that uses a dedicated user account that DOES have access to that site and destination list.  Then your App essentially has access to the site, but your end users do not.